# How to insert some common data using CSV upload?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

With CSV upload feature I can upload all my repeating data to my MySQL database. Suppose I have some fields like:

```
+------+-------+-----+--------+
| Year | Month | Day | Figure |
+------+-------+-----+--------+
  2012    01      01     200
  2012    01      02     303
  2012    01      03     632
  ...
  2012    01      31     323
+------+-------+-----+--------+
```

In my datasheet, I have two things in common:

- Year
- Month

What CSV does for me is:

```
2012,01,01,200
2012,01,02,303
2012,01,03,632
...
2012,01,31,323
```

A pure repeat in both the year and month field. If we can make these two fields common by any means in CSV, it'd be far better for the input-user.

So the bottom-line is:

- **HOW CAN WE INSERT SOME COMMON FIELDS WITH LESS INPUT USING CSV UPLOAD?**

Comment: why **ALL CAPS AND ALL BOLD** ?

Comment: Nothing unusual. :) It's just a style of mine. To emphasis on the main question. :) We better speak on the topic.

Comment: switch to a different data format. like `xml`

Comment: @MikeW: You failed to understand the basic question. Please make a revision. I want a solution for repeating data - the given scenario is just an example. :(

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I think you've failed to understand my point.

Comment: How do you imagine representing the data coming in... in csv as well with blank inputs?

Answer (score 0):

As @DevZer0 suggests, CSV is not a good choice of empty fields (or missing fields).

If you want to use text-based solution, you can try JSON / XML.

If you want to use managed approach, you can try to use DBMS, e.g. MySQL / MSSQL.

Or a mix of above, SQLite, a file-based database system.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really speak to how this would integrate with the wordpress plugin you speak of but to employ a technique where blank columns are populated with the values of the previous record you could do something like this (assumes there is a header line in the csv file that has unique field names).

```
<?php
$fp = fopen($csvFile, "r");
// get the header line

$header = fgetcsv($fp);
// seed the previous record array
$previousRec = array_combine($header, array_fill(0, count($header), ""));

while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)){
    $row = array_combine($header, $row);
    // filter with a closure requires php 5.3
    $filtered = array_filter($row, function($a){ return trim($a) !== "";});

    // merge the new data on top of the old with filtered values gone.
    $row = array_merge($previousRec, $filtered);

    // do something with row

    // store the row as the previousRec for the next time arround.
    $previousRec = $row;
}
```